# How can I block these windows that appear in web pages when scolling down?

Tags: firefox, html, browser-addons, plugins, css

I would like to know if it is possible to block these type of windows that appear when you scroll to the bottom of the web page or even when you just load them. It seems to me they are CSS. Generally they try to force you to subscribe to a newsletter or register to the website.

I use Firefox 36

[image]

Comment: While `@Dean-meehan` mentioned a standard way of getting rid of such things, I suppose by blocking you meant permanently. Therefore, I suggest a very easy approach which is an addon Nuke Anything Advanced [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/nuke-anything-enhanced/). It gives you two options : 1) Temporary, 2) Permanent. I prefer permanent when I know I'll come back later again to this site.

Comment: Thanks, but this requires one by one editing if I understand. I want to prevent loading those windows in any web page.

Comment: No, you don't need editing at all. All you need to is install the addon, right-click on the dialog which you want to remove, and select `Remove Object`. Done.

Comment: @Techle007 please read the question, it is not an ad and it is not js pop  up.

Comment: @Gabriel: The popup doesn't know whether its content is advertising.  Did you try the solutions to see whether they work?

Comment: Gabriel, please read the link Techie007 cites - it's about a javascript modal popup (aka an overlay)

Comment: @Dave. i read it thanks but there is no solution to prevent them from loading there. I am truing BehindTheOverlay anyway, but it does not prevent loding.

Comment: @fixer1234 there is no solution here or in the link. Disabling js is not an option as is not one by one editing. Maybe what I want is not possible.

Comment: Who deleted the link in the question? it served as an example where to test. I need the link to test!

Comment: BehindTheOverlay does not many sense to me, what is the difference between using the plugin and the x icon to close the window? Useful only in case there is no close icon.

Comment: It seems what I want (prevent the window from loading in every site) is not possible. Also, someone posted a similar question as linked but the answers do not match my needs. Thanks anyway for your comments!

Comment: @Gabriel: the edit history has all previous versions of the question, including your link.  Click on the "Edited <time>" link center bottom of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I do it manually using chrome.

1. Right click the gray around the item
2. Click inspect element
3. A developer window opens and shows the html of the popup
4. Right click the top line and click delete node
5. Press F12 to get rid of the developer window

Comment: Thanks this could be useful in case of a malicious window that has no close button , I want to prevent the window loading.

Comment: Are your writing a chrome plugin or something? It would need to be done that way or injecting code into the page. It generally isn't a window but some code in the page like the rest. Unless it loads with the popup, the code to pop it up is Javascript so by disabling Javascript you could stop these.

Comment: @DeanMeehan But disabling Javascript means disabling a lot of functionality. The trade off is way too much. :)

Comment: @Firelord Why exactly do you want to disable them? You could look for extentions to do this for you on the market that disdained them by injecting the Javascript into the page or setting the appropriate CSS, but each page is different so there is no full fullproof way